# How to load CARET quickly in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, caret, r2u

Surprised this hasn't been asked before.

I love using R in Google Colab but installing the caret package usually takes 5-7 minutes.
Is there any faster way to do it (can I use r2u)? Thanks!